# PHP convert time from UTC (TZD) format to "normal" time

Tags: php, time, format, utc

I have a feed that gives me times (not datetimes) in this format: "`20:00:00.000+03:00`"

I need to convert it to display just "`20:00`"
I know that I can do it using substr and cutting out the rest of the string, but that seems more like a hack and makes me wonder if it can produce bad results.

I already tried doing `date('H:m', strtotime("20:00:00.000+03:00"));` but it gives me `20:10` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right, except for the first argument :

```
date('H:i', strtotime("20:00:00.000+03:00"));
```

Will output the result you are expecting for.

Answer (score 0):

Not `H:m`, but `H:i`. check the [date format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: d'oh! :D:D:D thanks for pointing it out. sometimes it's a silly mistake that makes you stuck...